# Multiple Cases For Same Result Column

Tags: t-sql

Have a table where one of the columns has all of the info I need for a report.
I want to substring certain portions of this column as a column in this report, but the problem is that this column has results from 3 varying character lengths.

Example:

```
Row1: 20180101_ABC_12
Row2: 20180102_DEFG_23
Row3: 20180103_HIJKL_45
```

In this particular example I want the middle portion (eg. ABC) to be a column called 'Initials', problem is I am using CASE logic for each LEN. Not sure else how to achieve this.

My sample query below. It pulls all of the possible options, but as separate columns. What would I need to do to have these 3 options pull into one column, let's call it 'Initials'?

Thanks

```
SELECT
    FileName
    , CASE WHEN LEN(FileName) = 10 THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, 10, 3) ELSE NULL END
    , CASE WHEN LEN(FileName) = 11 THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, 10, 4) ELSE NULL END
    , CASE WHEN LEN(FileName) = 12 THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, 10, 5) ELSE NULL END
FROM File
```

Answer (score 1):

In Tableau, you would accomplish this using a calculated field.

Initials:

```
CASE LEN(FileName)
    WHEN 10 THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, 10, 3)
    WHEN 11 THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, 10, 4)
    WHEN 12 THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, 10, 5)
END
```

Or maybe

```
SUBSTRING(FileName
         ,10
         ,CASE LEN(FileName)
              WHEN 10 THEN 3
              WHEN 11 THEN 4
              WHEN 12 THEN 5
          END
          )
```

But barring the more technical aspect, this can be solved with math (assuming your data is either limited to the 10, 11, and 12, or that the pattern holds):

```
SUBSTRING(FileName
          ,10
          ,LEN(FileName)-7
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 1 [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement covering every possible case and not 3 separate ones, because each one creates a new column:

```
SELECT
    FileName
    , CASE LEN(FileName) 
        WHEN 10 THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, 10, 3)
        WHEN 11 THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, 10, 4)
        WHEN 12 THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, 10, 5) 
        ELSE NULL 
      END AS Initials
FROM File
```

Another way to get everything between the 2 `_`:

```
SELECT
    FileName
    , substring(
        left(FileName, len(FileName) - charindex('_', reverse(FileName) + '_')), 
        charindex('_', FileName) + 1,
        len(FileName)
    )  AS Initials
FROM File
```

but from your logic I assume that the values in column `FileName` have the same patern:

```
<9 digits>_<Initials>_<2 digits>
```

If this is the case then you can get what you want like this:

```
SELECT
    FileName
    , substring(FileName, 10, len(FileName) - 12) AS Initials
FROM File
```